# Can I connect my acer to 4k monitor?

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, acer-aspire

I am wondering can I connect my ACER ASPIRE 5 A517-51G to a 4k monitor. My laptop has a hdmi but I don't know if is it hdmi 2.0 or not. Laptop has integrated intel UHD 620 and a seperate graphics card MX150.
I checked online for a few hours and checked user manual but still no information.
This is important because I don't know if I should buy 4k monitor or not.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I have read, this laptop/GFX setup supports HDMI 1.4 and although you can get up to 4096x2304 out of it, it will be at a lowly 24Hz and will ***suck eggs***.

This can not be improved as it is a limitation of the port on this laptop.

Best thing to do?  BORROW a 4k monitor and HDMI2 cable and try it as acer is very wishy-washy on the specifics of the hardware.  I might be wrong.. but probably not.

Comment: thanks for the answer, could I then buy 1440p monitor?Will it be supported via hdmi 1.4

Comment: Yes, it will.  At least this is a good laptop for the money.